# ImageResizer 404 error with query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Install all by [imageresizing.net/docs](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install)

My *resizer.debug.ashx* work fine.

When i go to url like http://localhost:58663/images/blank_obj_img.png i download my image, but when i add query parameters like ?width=50&height=50 i get 404 page

Who know WTF? Debug page show me all is good and i can download image but cannot resizing

Comment: Try your URLs look like img.png.ashx?width=50&height=50?

Comment: Commands to set height and width of your image may treated as query string, perhaps you need to include a string parameter value on your action method to pass the query string.

Comment: with .ashx error is too

Answer (score 1):

You can need to follow this:

```
<!-- Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all requests to ASP.NET, 
you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 -->

<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true"/>
```

Comment: this setting included before and .ashx in url not working

Comment: Try add <add name="StaticPngImages" path="*.png" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" /> to the handlers of web.config

Comment: not work again, i change my project to http://imageprocessor.org this one, just install from nuget and run project. It's work perfect!

Comment: Thanks, just adding `.ashx` after the image file extension did the trick right away.